# C cut char arry and save binary data from socket

Tags: c, sockets, binary, buffer

I'm currently writing a small program in C++ (on a Mac, and with some C code in it) and need to retrieve binary data from a socket (which works well), but I also need to cut off the HTTP header.

So basically, I connect to a server, send a HTTP GET request, and get a HTTP 200 standard header followed by the binary data. I do only need the binary data and the Content-Length: field of the header.

My function so far:

```
void read_binary_data(ssize_t len,long long remain_data, FILE *fd, int sock){

    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    int checker = 0;
    int curr_position = 0;

    while (((len = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0) && (remain_data > 0)){

        // if(checker == 4) => http header until curr_position+1, data starts at curr_position+2
        for(char *pointer = buffer; curr_position <= len ; pointer++){

            if(*pointer == '\r' || *pointer == '\n'){
                checker++;
            }
            else{
                checker = 0;
            }

            if(checker == 4){
                break;
            }
            curr_position++;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len, fd);
        remain_data -= len;
    }
}
```

I would initially pass remain_data = 999 just to get into the while loop (and yes I need some error handling there but that's not the problem at the moment).

Now the `for()` loop should check for the '\r\n\r\n' at the end of a HTTP header; would I get it like that?

And then, how could I copy the binary data from buffer to another buffer to write it with fwrite() to a file? (without the HTTP header)

That would be sufficient for me, but I thought I could also try to "rerun" this function with the extracted 'Content-Length:' information to fill remain_data.. guess that's not needed anymore after the while() loop is completed.

But then again, can the `recv()` function return <= 0 even if there's still data left to read?

**So to conclude:**

- is my `for()` loop correct?
- how can I cut the HTTP header from buffer?
- can I safely delete the '&& (remain_data > 0)'?

Comment: You don't need to 'cut' the HTTP header from buffer; you simply need to start writing from the position where the body starts (and subtract the length of the header from it.  You should put the test on `remain_data` before the attempt to `recv()`.  Why is `len` a parameter when the first thing you do is overwrite it with the value from `recv()`?

Comment: Note that after the first time you find the end of header marker, you no longer want to look for it.  At the moment, if you read a second packet, you'll look for the end of header again, which means you'll ignore a lot of relevant data.

Comment: i passed len as argument because i first used this function in a different programm where i knew the data length before running recv()

Comment: Seeing `int`, `ssize_t` and `long long` "randomly" being mixed up hurts my eyes. All but `len` should really just be `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is for loop correct?

No, it isn't

Your `if(checker == 4)` could be true even if you have `"\r\r\r\r"` or all combination of two chars

You could write

```
char *pointer = buffer;
int remaining = len;
for(; remaining ; remaining--)
{
    if ((*pointer == '\r') && (remaining > 3))
    {
        if (!strncmp(pointer, "\r\n\r\n", 4))
        {
           pointer+=4;
           remaining-=4;
           break;
        }
    }

    pointer++;
}
```

> how can i cut the HTTP header from buffer?

I'm not sure I'm getting you.
If you need to copy all data after `"\r\n\r\n"` you could do, based on the code above:

```
fwrite(pointer, sizeof(char), remaining, fd);
```

> can i safely delete the '&& (remain_data > 0)'?

You could if the sender do it for you: if the sender sends you the correct amount of data you need.

Comment: okay i get the correct for(), ty. Now when passing remaining and pointer to fwrite(), does fwrite write from the begin of pointer (after '\r\n\r\n' in buffer) until the end of pointer/buffer, or from the begin of buffer until remaining?

Comment: @user1641602 I edited. In that way it start copying from the char after `"\r\n\r\n"` for `remaining` bytes

Comment: @user1641602 If it's enough don't forget to close the question as answered.